# Show that $S=\{x+iy: x,y \in \mathbb{R}, xy \ge 0\}$ is not a subfield of the complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S$ be the subset of the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ defined as  $S=\{x+iy: x,y \in \mathbb{R}, xy \ge 0\}$.

I want to show that $S$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is the Complex system. I understand that I have to find an axiom which fails for $S$, but is the question asking for me to find an axiom that works in the reals but fails in the complex?

Comment: There aren't that many axioms. Just go through them one by one and see if you can verify that they hold.

Comment: Do you know the geometric interpretation of multiplication? If yes, draw a picture of the subset you consider and it should be fairly direct to come up with a reason why it is not a field.

Comment: About your last question: $\Bbb C$ is a field, its subset $S$ is not. $\Bbb R$ is also a field. The formula for $S$ might have an analogous one for $\Bbb R$, say, $x\ge 0$, and it still doesn't define a subfield.

Comment: The inverse of $i$ is $-i$, which lies outside $S$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Actually, this is not true (perhaps you saw it as $x, y \ge 0$).

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically $S$ is the first and third quadrants along with the axes in the complex plane. It is not a subfield as it does not have closure under addition: For example take $u=-2-2i$ and $v=1+3i$. Now $u$ and $v$ are in $S$ since $-2\times-2=4\ge0$ for $u$, and $1\times3=3\ge0$ for $v$. Now consider $u+v=(-2+1)+(-2+3)i=-1+1i$ and we see $u+v$ is not in $S$ since $-1\times1=-1<0$.